# Push notification not showing when app is killed

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an application that is enabled to receive remote notification and perform background tasks.
I've set up `Background Modes` for `Background fetch` and `Remote notifications` and I can receive the notifications and perform the background fetch normally when the app is on foreground or background.

The problem is when the application is killed - the notification is not displayed, not even on the notification center, or as a banner, alert, etc.
I know that, if the application is killed, it will not be able to perform the background fetch. But I think it should at least display the notification.

On the `AppDelegate` I have implemented both methods:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

and

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
```

And I'm registering for notification using this:

```
UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Can anyone please advise me what could be wrong/missing from my side?